# Button OnClickListener not working

Tags: android-layout, onclicklistener, android-button, buttonclick

I have a button, when I click a dialog box appears. The problem is, the `setOnClickListener` is not responding to my button.

Here is my Java code:

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(usage);

    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(price);

    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Button3");
            mainDialog3 = new Dialog(Advice.this);
            mainDialog3.setContentView(R.layout.fuel);
            mainDialog3.setCancelable(true);

            mainDialog3.show();
            Window window = mainDialog3.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        }
    });


private View.OnClickListener usage = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Button1");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button 1",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mainDialog1 = new Dialog(Advice.this);
        mainDialog1.setContentView(R.layout.usage);
        mainDialog1.setCancelable(true);

        mainDialog1.show();
        Window window = mainDialog1.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    }
};

private View.OnClickListener price = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Button2");
        mainDialog2 = new Dialog(Advice.this);
        mainDialog2.setContentView(R.layout.price);
        mainDialog2.setCancelable(true);

        mainDialog2.show();
        Window window = mainDialog2.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    }

};
```

The problem is with button 1 (`b1`). The rest of the buttons (`b2`, `b3`) work perfectly fine. Here is my XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button7"
    android:text="Edit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Edit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Edit" />
```

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure the button you are clicking is button1?  It seems like you have a number of buttons all with the same text ("Edit") in a RelativeLayout.  Is it possible that another button is sitting on top of what you think is button1, thus preventing it from being clicked on?

Comment: yes i checked no other button is overlapping the button. Instead i added a new button and checked but still the same problem.

Comment: Hey thank you so much, i don't know where was the problem, but it worked now.

Comment: @IrshadKhan: when editing posts, please try and edit more than just a few words -- try and fix up as many issues as you can find in a post as possible. If a suggested edit only improves a post a tiny bit, it may be rejected as "too minor". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the click listener manually in the code. The easiest way, to do this is to add the callback in the XML.

Like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button7"
    android:onClick="foo"
    android:text="Edit" />
```

If you use eclipse with the android tools, you can set this property directly in the XML editor. Then you define a function in your code named after the Click property and it will be called automatically.

```
public void foo(View oView)
{
    Button cklicked ...
}
```

You can also set a click listener dynamically, but this you need only if you create buttons on the fly like this:

```
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.list_manager_add);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            button pressed...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -8):

try  `b1.setOnClickListener(usage);`
instead of  `b1.setOnClickListener(usage);` in your code it will work..brother

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: Try eating instead of putting food in your mouth?