# Error in setOnClickListener

Tags: android

I am new to android and i am trying to change the text by clicking button but i am getting the error "can not resolve setOnClickListener" on third line.how can i resolve this?

```
  Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.setOnClickListener(){   //error in this line
                    public void onclick(View v){
                        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        t.setText("text changed!");
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button OnClickListener not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335135/button-onclicklistener-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use View

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      t.setText("text changed!");
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you answered before me, didnt see. +1 .

Answer (score 2):

Can you try like :

```
TextView t;
Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
   t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
   b.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        t.setText("text changed!");
        }
   });
}
```

Also can you post your `Xml` too, for reference

Answer (score 2):

When you want to ser a click listener in a `Button`, you should use `setOnClickListener` like you did but the argument must be an instance of `Button.OnClickListener()`, so you have to use `new` to create that instance. Beacuase `Button.OnClickListener` is an `interface`, you also have to implement `public void onClick(View v)` like you did.

Please, try this:

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t.setText("text changed!");
    }
});
```